# Получение представления символа И кодировки utf-8 в кодировке cp1251

Tags: java

Такая ситуация - нужно передать utf-8 строку перекодированную в cp1251. В строке встретилась заглавная буква И, которая перекодировалась некорректно

```
    String message = "И волга";
    System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset() + "\n");
    //UTF-8

    String cpToUtf = new String(message.getBytes("utf-8"), "cp1251");
    System.out.println("cpToUtf: " + cpToUtf);
    //cpToUtf: Р� РІРѕР»РіР°

    String cpToUtfToCp = new String(cpToUtf.getBytes("cp1251"), "utf-8");
    System.out.println("cpToUtfToCp: " + cpToUtfToCp);
    //cpToUtf: cpToUtfToCp: �? волга - как итог обратно также ломано
```

Подскажите, как это можно побороть?

Comment: Что-то ничего не понятно. Передать кому и как? Показанный код и близко не занимается реальным перекодированием, а лишь ломает строки.

Comment: Мне надо передать именно такую крокозябру вида РІРѕР»РіР°, т.е. представление массива байт utf-8 в кодировке cp1251 (сторонний сервис хочет получить именно ее, почему - понятия не имею). Но у них при обратном переводе ломается символ И. Повторюсь, для чего эти перекодирования им - без понятия, но вот надо так.

Comment: Как именно вы передаёте строку в сторонний сервис? Есть ощущение, будто вы неправильно поняли работу сервиса и оттого запутались ([Ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710))

Comment: Если вы берете кодировку А, переводите в байты и потом пытаетесь из байт получить кодировку Б, то это вроде ожидаемо, что какие то символы сломаются.

Comment: В утф-8 не аскей буква занимает 2 байта, когда вы вызываете getBytes(..) e у вас будет 0xD0 0x98 вместо буквы "И", Видимо есть какой-то бажок у new String() если он начало строки неправильно интерпретирует. пробовал в порядке теста сделать тоже самое через NPP с миме тулз - нормально отрабатывает. может быть у вас что-то в строке в начале перед буквой "И" есть еще? и на печать оно не выводится, сделайте дамп байт в строке. попробуем понять в чем беда.

Comment: `message.getBytes("utf-8"): D0 98 20 D0 B2 D0 BE D0 BB D0 B3 D0 B0 
(new String(message.getBytes("utf-8"), "cp1251")).getBytes("cp1251"): D0 3F 20 D0 B2 D0 BE D0 BB D0 B3 D0 B0 `